# Update Array If Value Found Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key-value

Is there a way to update a part of a multidimensional array if a value is found? For example I have an array $foo with an updated chunck of $foo called $bar. I'd like to merge $bar into $foo when some_id = 123.

Unfortunately I can't change some_id and the some_id key is the same for all arrays. The bar key unfortunately must also stay the same.

```
$foo = array(
  0 => array(
    bar => array(
      some_id => 123,
      a => 1 
    )
  ), 
  1 => array(
    bar => array(
      some_id => 234,
      a => 5
    )
  )
)

$update_bar = array(
    some_id => 123,
    a => 10
)
```

Comment: `$foo[bar] = $update_bar`

Comment: That would update both bar arrays. The goal is to only update the bar where some_id = 123.

Comment: Having array with same keys is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way is:

```
foreach ($foo as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['some_id'] == 123) {
        $foo[$key] = $updated_bar;
        break;
    }
}
```

And if `some_id` value is really important and unique, it's better to rebuild `$foo` like:

```
$foo = array(
   // use some_id as key
   123 => array(
     a => 1 
   ),
   234 => array(
     a => 5
   )
);

// and update without any `foreach`
$foo[123] = array(a => new_val)
```

Comment: Since it's a multidimensional array the foreach function would need to be called recursively if $value is_array(). Then can $key be updated by reference?

Comment: Please provide proper array structure. What you have now in a question doesn't need any `recursive`ness

Answer (score 0):

***Solution 1:***

You can use `reference variable` in the `foreach` loop that will assign to the looping variable itself.

```
foreach ($multifoo as &$foo) {
    $foo['bar']['a'] = ($update_bar['some_id'] == $foo['bar']['some_id']) ? $update_bar['a'] : $foo['bar']['a'];
}
print_r($multifoo);
```

***Solution 2:***

You can use `array_map` function and return it the changed variable.

```
$multifoo = array_map(function ($foo) use ($update_bar) {
    if ($update_bar['some_id'] == $foo['bar']['some_id']) {
        $foo['bar']['a'] = $update_bar['a'];
    }
    return $foo;
}, $multifoo);
print_r($multifoo);
```

Demo link: https://3v4l.org/u7uL4